# PrimeNg P-dropdown Get and Set Value Details?

Tags: angular, toolstripdropdown, primeng-dropdowns

1.I need an Explanation about, when I select the value at the time my JSON value does not set the corresponding selection.

2.Binding of [optionLabel] & optionLabel doubt?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ljsuim?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ljsuim?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Plz any one help me.